# Why ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan() can't scan @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have four javaclass like this;

[image]

I use spring 5.3.1 ; openjdk 11 ;and this my code;

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    var registry = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();

    var scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(registry);

    scanner.setIncludeAnnotationConfig(false);

    scanner.scan("org.scx.*");

    for (var name : registry.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.err.println(name);
    }
}
```

**ClassOne.java**

```
@Component
public class ClassOne {

}
```

**ClassTwo.java**

```
@Component
public class ClassTwo {

    @Bean
    public ClassThree classThree() {
        return new ClassThree();
    }
}
```

**ClassThree.java**

```
public class ClassThree {

}
```

Now I run it; Just print these;

```
classOne
classTwo
```

I can't find ClassThree why ?
what should I do please.

I finished ; Use SpringApplicationRunListener ;Thank everyone very much

Comment: Did you try without the `setIncludeAnnotationConfig(false)`? With `false`, it doesn't register **annotation config** post-processors, and `@Bean` is an annotation for configuring beans.

Comment: Because it only is that, a scanner. It will detect the `ClassTwo` but it won't process annotations on classes. That is the task of the `ApplicationContext` **not** the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html) says:

> A bean definition scanner that detects bean candidates on the classpath, registering corresponding bean definitions with a given registry (`BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext`).
>
> Candidate classes are detected through configurable type filters. The default filters include classes that are annotated with Spring's `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, or `@Controller` stereotype.

Basically, this is the internal workhorse for scanning the classpath for classes annotated with `@Component` or derived `@Component` annotation, i.e. an annotation that is itself annotated with `@Component`.

That's it. It only scans for `@Component` annotated classes. Processing of `@Bean` annotated methods is not handled by this class. That is usually done by the [`refresh()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--) method of a [`ConfigurableApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html).